# Contradictory results of the ADF test in R

Tags: r, p-value, stata, augmented-dickey-fuller

I used the urca pacakge in R to run the ADF test and got the following:

[image]

It seems to me the results are quite contradictory:

- Using the statistic, we fail to reject the null hypothesis;
- However, using the p-value, we could reject the null hypothesis at any significance level.

So I am confused about the result.

Besides, I also used Stata to ADF test the same data and got the following result:
[image]

Like what I did in R, I also performed the ADF test with only the drift. The test statistc is almost the same as the one in the R. However the p-value is quite different. And what seems more strange is the cricital value, which I could not find in dickey fuller critical value table...

Could anyone tell me what is going on here?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You are misinterpreting the p-value generate in the R output.  The is the p-value associated with the usual F-Test that all coefficients are zero.  It is not the p-value for the ADF test.

The concerning part about these separate outputs is that critical values are different.  For a ADF test with a drift (i.e. a constant) the critical values from the R output are [correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Dickey%E2%80%93Fuller_test).

I appears that the STATA is incorrect because for some reason it does not include the drift.  Look at the STATA regression output, it has z in levels and in first difference but no intercept.  In contrast, the R output is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, Jacob! In this sense, the ADF test in the urca package would not return a p-value for the test statistic?

Comment: Nope, it does not look like `ur.ca::ur.df` returns a p-value.  I suspect that the package only contains critical values and not the entire distribution of each ADF test.  As a result, this package can not calculate a p-value.